# How to create spiral chart with d3 pack in d3 v7?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I was able to create a chart with d3 pack but want to position circles in spiral layout how can i position the circles in pack
this the my code

```
const sortBubble = () => {
        setShowBackButton(true)

        const svg = d3.select(svgReference.current)
        svg.selectAll('*').remove()

        const colorScale = createColorScale()
        const valueScale = createValueScale(sortChartData)

        svg.append('g').attr('class', 'circle-group')

        const root = d3
            .hierarchy({
                children: sortChartData
            })
            .sum(d => d.value)
            .sort((a, b) => a.value - b.value)
        const nodes = root.descendants().filter(d => !d.children)

        d3
            .pack()
            .size([width / 2, height / 2])
            .padding(15)(root)

        svg
            .selectAll('.bubbleNode')
            .data(nodes)
            .enter()
            .append('circle')
            .attr('class', 'bubbleNode')
            .attr('cx', d => d.x ?? 0)
            .attr('cy', d => d.y ?? 0)
            .attr(
                'r',
                d =>
                    calculateRadius(d, bubbleData, valueScale) + COLLISION_RADIUS_FACTOR
            )
            .attr('fill', d => colorScale(d.value))
            .attr('transform', d => `translate(${d.x},${d.y})`)
    }
[Getting chart like this with this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xzx8O.png)
```

Please someone can tell me how can i position the circles in spiral pattern

[Here the required style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgEgC.png)

Answer (score 1):

here is sample showing a spiral with each node point a little circle.

the part of code drawing circle:

```
// Generate points for the spiral
const spiralPoints = [];
for (let angle = 0; angle < 10 * Math.PI; angle += angleIncrement) {
    const x = centerX + radius * angle * Math.cos(angle);
    const y = centerY + radius * angle * Math.sin(angle);
    spiralPoints.push({ x, y });
}
// Draw circles at each spiral point
svg.selectAll('circle')
    .data(spiralPoints)
    .enter().append('circle')
    .attr('cx', d => d.x)
    .attr('cy', d => d.y)
    .attr('r', 5)  // Circle radius
    .attr('fill', 'red');  // Circle color
```

You generate points inside an array....

if you want add multiple colors, just add function to fill attribute (for example)

```js
    // Set up SVG container
    const svgWidth = 600;
    const svgHeight = 400;
    const svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
        .attr('width', svgWidth)
        .attr('height', svgHeight);

    // Spiral parameters
    const centerX = svgWidth / 2;
    const centerY = svgHeight / 2;
    const radius = 10;
    const angleIncrement = 0.1;

    // Generate points for the spiral
    const spiralPoints = [];
    for (let angle = 0; angle < 10 * Math.PI; angle += angleIncrement) {
        const x = centerX + radius * angle * Math.cos(angle);
        const y = centerY + radius * angle * Math.sin(angle);
        spiralPoints.push({ x, y });
    }

    // Draw circles at each spiral point
    svg.selectAll('circle')
        .data(spiralPoints)
        .enter().append('circle')
        .attr('cx', d => d.x)
        .attr('cy', d => d.y)
        .attr('r', 5)  // Circle radius
        .attr('fill', 'red');  // Circle color
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Spiral Drawing with D3.js</title>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but it does not create a same spiral pattern i require also i want to achive this by using the d3.pack layout in earlier version of d3 v3 where you can pass the data in sorted format like ascending or descending and the circles positioned according to it.

Comment: your problem was to draw circles , but to adapt to your solution, you should show a functional sample

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Pritamkedare/tkesd54c/9/
here is the working example in d3 v3 i am trying to implement same in d3 v7 can you help me how can i do it?